# Can we use any product data in Oracle Commerce Cloud(OCC) Widgets?

Tags: oracle, oracle-commerce-cloud

If so, how can I add Product or Category data to my Custom Widget in Oracle Commerce Cloud (OCC)?

And should I use knockout js while doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: you should read tutorial or something. this topic is off topic and very broad for SO

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add product/category specific data in your custom widgets. 
If you want to see the view model of the data added to products while catalog creation then simply add the Knockout Js context debugger from chrome then you can inspect and see the data associated to products in developer tools.

To fetch the data in your template you need to use knockout JS bindings.
Refer to the link below for learning about knockouts JS bindings: 
https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html[Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97801_01/Cloud.18C/index.html)

Also, check out OCC documentations [OCC 18C Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97801_01/Cloud.18C/index.html)

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: oracle recently changed to react js components. but knockout.js still do the job of add products and category data on custom widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Generally, product and category data is directly available page specific, however, you can use Rest APIs to fetch specific data for other pages. And, yes you should use knockout.js.